# Java XML: Keeping a copy of a partial XML tree when parsing from a socket

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have a socket feeding into a sax parser, formatted as a ISO 8859/1 stream. Every so often there is an invalid character, and I get a SAXParseException with a row and column where that happened, so I need to see what the data is at that point (or more importantly log it).

Originally the lines that processed the data were:

```
InputSource is = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "ISO8859_1"));
XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
reader.setContentHandler(new ResponseParseHandler(etc, id));
reader.parse(is);
```

Problem is that I can't get the data after the event of this happening, so I changed it to read into a large byte buffer, convert it to a string and parse that data with a StringReader. Unfortunately the data coming from the socket is spread out in small chunks over a long time, so it will start with the root tag when it first connects, but then there will be thousands of separate messages without a closing tag.

Because I am parsing these strings individually when they come in the first one has an error that it doesn't have a closing tag, and the following ones error as they don't have a base tag. This doesn't happen with the socket as I assume the stream is still open

Presumably I can feed these strings to another reader / writer but it seems to be getting really complicated just to find out what the block of data was at the time of the error.

Is there something really simple I am missing here?

Comment: it means you getting data as xml in stream and you want to check where errors are occurred.

Comment: yes, that is what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I had a problem similar to this, I solved it with a `SplittingWriter`. This was a decorator style class around two other `Writer`s, and when something "wrote" to the `SplittingWriter` it simply delegated the write call to both of its two underlying `Writer`s.

In your case, you would want something like a `SplittingInputStreamReader`, which would implement `InputStreamReader` and which you would pass in to `InputSource` instead of the `InputStreamReader` you are using at the moment.

In its constructor the `SplittingInputStreamReader` would take your current `InputStreamReader` and some other object, lets call it `Foo`. The implementation of the `read` methods on `SplittingInputStreamReader` would then delegate the read calls to the underlying `InputStreamReader`, push the results of those calls to `Foo`, and then return the result of those calls back to the thing that called it. So your implementation of the `int read()` method would be something like:

```
   @Override
   public int read() {
       int r = this.inputStreamReader.read();
       this.foo.submit(r);
       return r;
   }
```

That way, as you read via the `SplittingInputStreamReader`, you also write to `Foo`, allowing you to see where the write stopped assuming you gave `Foo` a decent interface. In the end, after implementing `SplittingInputStreamReader` and `Foo`, your code would look something like this:

```
Foo streamCapture = new Foo();
SplittingInputStreamReader streamReader = new SplittingInputStreamReader(
   new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "ISO8859_1"), streamCapture);
InputSource is = new InputSource(streamReader);
XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
reader.setContentHandler(new ResponseParseHandler(etc, id));
reader.parse(is);
// After parse, if there was an error, check what is in Foo streamCapture
```

Comment: Kinda like `org.apache.commons.io.input.TeeInputStream`

Comment: Just had a look at that, and - Yes. In that instance Foo is the equivalent of the OutputStream "branch".

Comment: Sounds like the plan and was sort of where I was heading, but I went too far out!. Had to divert onto other things but will try it out as soon as possible, and mark as answered if it all works, thanks

Comment: Ultimately spliting the InputStreamReader didn't work, it was working on the base stream so I had to split the InputStream and take an output from there (which did work).

Answer (score 1):

You can provide your own InputStreamReader custom impl that keeps a reference to the content you need (e.g. MyInputStreamReader) and provides methods for you to get at the decoded content or last 1024 bytes of decoded content (or some capped amount).

Let the existing InputStreamReader impl do what it is already doing, just wrap it with some additional logic in a custom class then pass that to create the InputSource.